# The configuration section 'configsections' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I want to host a Wcf service on an IIS 10.0 on Windows Server 2016.

My app pool is **`v2.0`** Integrated and the `Wcf service` was built with **`3.5.`** Below `web.config` gets

```
The configuration section 'configsections' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.
```

Service runs fine with same config on a **w8.1 - IIS6.2** and on `older Windows Server versions`. What could be missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configsections>
     <sectiongroup name="system.web.extensions" type="system.web.configuration.systemwebextensionssectiongroup, system.web.extensions, version=3.5.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35">
       <sectiongroup name="scripting" type="system.web.configuration.scriptingsectiongroup, system.web.extensions, version=3.5.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35">
       </sectiongroup>
    </sectiongroup>
</configsections>
```

Comment: It *should* be `configSections` rather than `configsections`. Note the capital S in the middle. (Similarly, `sectionGroup` rather than `sectiongroup`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh my god! Thank you. Please enter this as answer so I can accept and wallow in my shame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
         <sectiongroup name="system.web.extensions" type="system.web.configuration.systemwebextensionssectiongroup, system.web.extensions, version=3.5.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35">
           <sectiongroup name="scripting" type="system.web.configuration.scriptingsectiongroup, system.web.extensions, version=3.5.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=31bf3856ad364e35">
           </sectiongroup>
        </sectiongroup>
    </configSections>
```

> [here is the full Article](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/11/The-configuration-section-system-web-extensions-cannot-be-read-because-it-is-missing-a-section-declaration.html)